# Build and deploy my application on on-premise server(accessed via vpn) using Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, deployment, build, devops, vpn

This might sound a little crazy but I'm asking this out of curiosity. Is it possible to build and deploy my application to an On-Premise server which can only be accessed by a vpn, using Jenkins? Assuming Jenkins is run on say a local machine(So I won't need internet access to use Jenkins) is it possible to connect Jenkins server to a vpn and do the rest of the job?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should be possible. That's the whole idea of a VPN. As long as you are connected to the VPN you should be able to connect to the internal network of your organization.

Comment: One more thing I'm not that familiar with types of private VPN, is it possible to keep the internet access while connected to the VPN. So that I can use Jenkins remotely too, say one running on an EC2 instance. I currently use a vpn, where I can access all the websites without any interruption.

Comment: This depends on the VPN client/configurations and the organization's policies. In some Organizations, the internet is not accessible once connected to the VPN.